# To avoid multiple database calls blocking each other in a Go web app handler, are goroutines + syncGroup the only way?

Tags: go, goroutine

Having taken a look at several web application examples and boilerplates, the approach they take tends to be in the form of this (I'm using a Gin handler here as an example, and imaginary User and Billing "repository" structs that fetch data from either a database or an external API. I omitted error handling to make the example shorter) :

```
func GetUserDetailsHandler(c *gin.Context) {
    //this result presumably comes from the app's database
    var userResult = UserRepository.FindById( c.getInt("user_id") )

    //assume that this result comes from a different data source (e.g: a different database) all together, hence why we're not just doing a join query with "User"
    var billingInfo = BillingRepository.FindById(  c.getInt("user_id")  )

    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H {
        user_data : userResult,
        billing_data : billingInfo,
    })

    return
}
```

In the above scenario, the call to "User.FindById" might use some kind of database driver, but as far as I'm aware, all available Golang database/ORM libraries return data in a "synchronous" fashion (e.g: as return values, not via channels). As such, the call to "User.FindById" will block until it's complete, before I can move on to executing "BillingInfo.FindById", which is not at all ideal since they can both work in parallel.

So I figured that the best idea was to make use of go routines + syncGroup to solve the problem. Something like this:

```
func GetUserDetailsHandler(c *gin.Context) {
    var waitGroup sync.WaitGroup

    userChannel := make(chan User);
    billingChannel := make(chan Billing)

    waitGroup.Add(1)
    go func() {
            defer waitGroup.Done()
            userChannel <- UserRepository.FindById( c.getInt("user_id") )               
    }()

    waitGroup.Add(1)
    go func(){
            defer waitGroup.Done()
            billingChannel <- BillingRepository.FindById(  c.getInt("user_id") )
    }()

    waitGroup.Wait()

    userInfo := <- userChannel
    billingInfo = <- billingChannel

    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H {
        user_data : userResult,
        billing_data : billingInfo,
    })

    return
}
```

Now, this presumably does the job. But it seems unnecessarily verbose to me, and potentially error prone (if I forget to "Add" to the waitGroup before any go routine, or if I forget to "Wait", then it all falls apart). Is this the only way to do this? Or is there something simpler that I'm missing out?

Comment: First question: *are you sure that you gain anything noticeable from doing the queries in parallel*? However you actually implement it, a 1% gain isn't worth chasing. Plus, if this is even a moderately high-volume application, you're going to max out DB connections in a hurry this way with many concurrent requests each executing queries in parallel.

Comment: There's also no reason whatsoever to use channels here. You can just close over a local variable to keep the results in, as long as you don't try to read from them until after the `waitGroup.Wait` call. The channels get you nothing in this case but added verbosity.

Comment: The above scenario is more of a toy question than anything else - in a real life app that may require fetching data from multiple different external APIs, the minor gains might stack up.

You make a good point on the channels, though. They don't seem necessary in this scenario. Never thought about that - I'm new to Go and was trying to learn more about Channels and I guess this new hammer made everything look like a nail.

Comment: It might help, it might not, it might create a bottleneck on connection pools/ports/network bandwidth/memory, it might not. I would *strongly* recommend against this kind of approach without thoroughly benchmarking and comparing with production-level loads to ensure this is actually an improvement and doesn't create new problems; and see if there are other ways to get what that performance gain (e.g. a local in-memory cache).

Comment: More to your question, go uses goroutines for concurrency, and `sync.WaitGroup` is _one_ way to synchronize them. Are you asking if you can use channels _or_ a `sync.WaitGroup`? Concurrency adds complexity, and you have to manage that, there's no free ride. What "other way" are you looking for?

Comment: @JimB -  "Are you asking if you can use channels or a sync.WaitGroup?" - Sort of. Or if there is any other solution that I'm missing out of the picture here. For instance, in JavaScript, you can handle asynchronous tasks with callback functions, generators, promises, async/await - I'm asking if I'm missing alternative ways of handling concurrency.

Though I've had it pointed out to me elsewhere that at least in my above scenario, I don't even need the WaitGroup since the channel accessors themselves (userInfo, billingInfo) would block until the channels return.

Comment: @aetheus: Once you remove the unnecessary pieces from your example above the concurrency is very simple; I would say much simpler to reason about compared to callbacks, generators, promises, etc.

Comment: I agree. Once I remove the unnecessary WaitGroup, the resulting code looks a lot simpler. I'm fairly used to the concept of using Promises/Futures for concurrency, and I guess mastering the use of goroutines/channels just takes some getting used to. 

Thanks for your time, JimB and Adrian

Answer (score 2):

maybe something like this

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func GetUserDetailsHander(c *gin.Context) {
    var userInfo USERINlFO
    var billingInfo BILLL

    err := parallel(
        func() (e error) {
            userInfo, e = UserRepository.FindById(c.getInt("user_id"))
            return
        },
        func() (e error) {
            billingInfo, e = BillingRepository.FindById(c.getInt("user_id"))
            return
        },
    )
    fmt.Println(err)

    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
        user_data:    userResult,
        billing_data: billingInfo,
    })

    return
}
func parallel(do ...func() error) error {
    var err error
    rcverr := make(chan error)
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for _, d := range do {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(do func() error) {
            rcverr <- do()
            wg.Done()
        }(d)
    }
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(rcverr)
    }()
    for range do {
        e := <-rcverr
        if e != nil {
            err = e // return here for fast path
        }
    }
    return err
}
```